# How to transfer songs from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm upgrading from a iPhone 6s to a iPhone 7. I have about 3000 songs on it from my library of approx. 6000.

Without going through the library unticking 3000 or so songs, is there any simpler way of transferring those songs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup your old iPhone to iTunes using a USB cable
2. Connect your new iPhone using a usb cable
3. Select "restore from backup" in iTunes.

Assuming the songs you are from your iTunes library, they will be transferred to the new iPhone.

Enjoy your music!

Please let me know if this solves your issue.